# What's a good simple free CAD program I can use for planning internal decorating of my house?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, cad

At the moment I'm using cut-to-scale pieces of paper to represent each piece of potential furniture. Is there a simple website or program which I can use instead?

The room's dimensions are set in stone, it's just lounges / beds etc. I need to spec out.

Must Be:

- Free
- Simple
- Windows 7 Compatible

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at **[Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/)**.

The free version will do the job well...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.homestyler.com/designer